# MySQL query slow because of separate indexes?

Tags: mysql, myisam

Here is my situation. I have a MySQL MyISAM table containing about 4 million records with a total of 13,3 GB of data. The table contains messages received from an external system. Two of the columns in the table keep track of a timestamp and a boolean whether the message is handled or not.

When using this query:

```
SELECT MIN(timestampCB) FROM webshop_cb_onx_message
```

The result shows up almost instantly.

However, I need to find the earliest timestamp of unhandled messages, like this:

```
SELECT MIN(timestampCB ) FROM webshop_cb_onx_message WHERE handled = 0
```

The results of this query show up after about 3 minutes, which is way too slow for the script I'm writing.

Both columns are individually indexed, not together. However, adding an index to the table would take incredibly long considering the amount of data that is in there already.

Does my problem originate from the fact that both columns are separatly indexed, and if so, does anyone have a solution to my issue other than adding another index?

Comment: Adding `timestampCB` onto the `handled` index would make the second query perform practically as well as the first.  The time to add the index would be well worth it if you commonly run the second query.

Comment: How many `handled` columns with `0` do exist? If the index on `handled` isn't very selective it's probably the issue here.

Comment: @André : At this point about 25% of the table's data has `handled` set to `0`.

Comment: Yep, *Steve* is right here; due to its low selectivity, the index on `handled`won't help so much anymore. So you have to add a combined index in order to push the search or - if this is really a no go - work with a temporary table / trigger that maintains this information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is commonly recommended that if the selectivity of an index over 20% then a full table scan is preferable over an index access. This would mean it is likely that your index on handled won't actually result in using the index but a full table scan given the selectivity.

A composite index of `handled, timestampCB` may actually improve the performance given its a composite index, even if the selectivity isn't great MySQL would most likely still use it - even if it didn't you could [force it's use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).

Comment: Thanks @Steve for the information. By using the `USE INDEX` statements I could indeed force MySQL into using or not using the indexes I have. However the performance issue was not fixed. 

I guess I'll wait a while and have my table add a composite index of both. Thanks for answering my question and concluding that seperate indexes is indeed the issue here.